# Cant find the e(fx)clipse IDE in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I followed the steps given in this [tutorial](https://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html).

But when I am searching for `e(fx)clipse` in the new Software Section there is no e(fx)clipse IDE only a Software called `e(fx)clipse - Minimal JavaFX OSGi integration bundles 3.5.0.201902220600`, with that FX isn't working properly.

My system configurations / Versions:

```
Java 8
eclipse: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
```

Comment: could you please try once again by https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/efxclipse. `just Drag to your running Eclipse workspace. Requires Eclipse Marketplace Client`

Comment: thanks! it worked.

Comment: Well, good to hear.